# Can I stream CloudWatch log group to lambda from another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Can I stream CloudWatch Log Group to a lambda from another account? I've tried to configure it from AWS Console but it shows me only the lambda from the current account.

**Hint:** **I am not interested** in the Amazon Kinesis solution. I know how to do it via subscriptions as it is described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CrossAccountSubscriptions.html

I am asking precisely about lambda from a different account.

P.S. I tried to add a subscription on a log group to a lambda from another account, as it is described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample), but I have received the following error:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the
>   PutSubscriptionFilter
>   operation: Cross-account lambda invocation passing is not allowed. You
>   must use                                          DestinationPolicies
>   to create cross account lambda triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Currently, no. This includes using a CloudWatch Logs Destination**

The limits of `PutSubscriptionFilter` are documented here in more detail: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutSubscriptionFilter.html

CloudWatch Logs only supports the streaming of log data to Lambda functions in the same account, despite the unclear error message that seems to suggest that it *might* be possible.

I suspect that the error message:

> You must use DestinationPolicies to create cross account lambda triggers.

Is somewhat generic to any service attempting cross-account lambda invocation, and makes sense in the case of services like SNS where you can add permissions to a topic to allow it.

Alternatively, you might be tempted to use a CloudWatch logs Destination to send to a Lambda function, however, destinations only support Kinesis.

The closest AWS comes to documenting this is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutDestination.html

Which says the following about the target ARN:

> The ARN of an Amazon Kinesis stream to which to deliver matching log events.

Despite this, on the off chance it was still possible, I attempted to follow these [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CreateDestination.html), substituting a Lambda function for the Kinesis stream and was met with this error on the final step, which I wasn't able to resolve.

```sh
$ aws logs put-destination --destination-name "testDestination" --target-arn "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<YOUR ACCOUNT ID HERE>:function:destinationtest" --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::<YOUR ACCOUNT ID HERE>:role/CWLtoLambdaRole"

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the PutDestination operation: Could not deliver test message to specified destination. Check if the destination is valid.
```

From all of this, I'm forced to conclude that the answer is still no for directly connecting a Lambda function to a CloudWatch Log across accounts. However, you can use a Kinesis stream in a separate account as a destination which you can then very easily subscribe a Lambda function to.

Comment: The answer is a bit outdate - It is possible right now https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutSubscriptionFilter.html#CWL-PutSubscriptionFilter-request-destinationArn

Comment: I’ve updated my answer, still not possible unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

seems like it is possible now?

From the docs:

```
destinationArn
The ARN of the destination to deliver matching log events to. Currently, the supported destinations are:

A logical destination (specified using an ARN) belonging to a different account, for cross-account delivery.
```